# Substrate error - consider giving `accuracy` a type

Tags: substrate

I ran into the same error, initially I tried with default nightly-2020-10-05, then nightly-2020-10-01 and nightly-2020-10-06... but nothing is working.

Steps followed to downgrade the nightly are :

- rustup uninstall nightly
- rustup install nightly-
- rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain
  nightly-
- WASM_BUILD_TOOLCHAIN=nightly- cargo build --release

I have tried on both Windows and Ubuntu 18.04 environment. But every time I get the same error.

[consider giving `accuracy` a type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozrYW.png)

Comment: Have you tried the new v2.0.1, yet? https://crates.io/crates/sp-io/2.0.1
It's meant to fix the build issues.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/7287

```sh
rustup default nightly-2020-10-06 && rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

Or just update to substrate 2.0.1, this issue is fixed in that version

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rustup` to manage your version,
make sure your **active toolchain** is like this:

`$ rustup show`

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2020-10-05-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2020-10-05-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.49.0-nightly (beb5ae474 2020-10-04)
```